# BeautifulSoup4 Python 3.4 Scraping Issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

Trying to pull data from a website that has a few different piece of information under identical tag names.
Ex:

```
<td class=pizza>cheese </td>
<td class=pizza> deluxe</td>
<td class=pizza> pepperoni</td>
<td class=pizza> raccoon</td>
<td class=pizza> mushshroom</td>
<td class=pizza> anchovy</td>
```

How do I write a line of web scraping (Using BeautifulSoup 4) to select one that won’t be cheese. (Say I want deluxe). Wouldn’t it be something along the lines of:

```
pizza = soup.find("td", {"class": "pizza"})
print (pizza) #This will give me cheese as a result, and I want deluxe.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want `cheese` specifically, you can filter it out using [a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
soup.find("td", class_="pizza", text=lambda text: text and text.strip() != "cheese")
```

Or, if you want the second `td` element with `class="pizza"`:

```
soup.find_all("td", class_="pizza")[1]
```